# Trying to implement a thread-safe cache

Tags: rust, hashmap, thread-safety, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement a shared-state, thread-safe cache, using a `HashMap` behind a `RwLock`. Ideally, I would like my interface to expose a single function, which -- given the key -- will return a reference to the value in the cache (populating it, first, if necessary). However, my intermediate-Rust intuition is telling me that this approach is going to suffer from at least the following problems:

1. Is it even possible to return a reference to the value? AFAIK, the `HashMap` is free to reallocate when required(*), so the lifetime of the reference is not the same as the `HashMap` and, effectively, non-deterministic (as far as the compiler's concerned). The `HashMap::entry` API returns a reference, but of course, it wouldn't be allowed to live longer than its enclosing scope. Is it therefore necessary to return a concrete value, forcing me to implement `Copy` for the value type?

   (*) Is this still true if the values don't implement `Copy`?
2. `RwLock` is new to me. I started with `Mutex`, but `RwLock` looks more appropriate, because of the expected access patterns to the cache (i.e., write once, per key, read many times). However, I'm not sure if one can "upgrade" a read lock into a read-write lock. The Rust documentation suggests that a read lock will block a write lock, which would lead to a deadlock in the way I am proposing/hoping it to work. Can I drop the read lock and replace it with the write lock, or is it easier to use a full `Mutex` from the outset?

As an aside, the function that fetches the value is async, so while I can use the `HashMap::entry` API, I can't use the `Entry` convenience functions (like `or_insert`)...

Anyway, maybe I'm a bit in over my head, but this is what I've got so far:

```rust
// NOTE The `Key` struct contains a reference, with lifetime `'key`
pub struct Cache<'key>(RwLock<HashMap<Key<'key>, Value>>);

impl<'cache, 'key> Cache<'key> {
    pub fn new() -> Arc<Self> {
        Arc::new(Self(RwLock::new(HashMap::new())))
    }

    // NOTE The key and value for the cache is derived from the `Payload` type
    pub async fn fetch(
        &'cache mut self,
        data: &'cache Payload<'key>
    ) -> Result<&'cache Value> {
        let cache = self.0.read()?;
        let key = data.into();

        Ok(match &mut cache.entry(key) {
            // Match arm type: &Value
            // FIXME This reference outlives the scope, which is a borrow violation
            Entry::Occupied(entry) => entry.get(),

            // Dragons be here...
            Entry::Vacant(ref mut slot) => {
                // FIXME How do I create a write lock here, without deadlocking on
                // the read lock that's still in scope?

                let value = data.get_value().await?;

                // FIXME `VacantEntry<'_, Key<'_>, Value>` doesn't implement `Copy`
                slot.insert(value)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `tokio` you should probably use `tokio::sync::RwLock` whose guards have a [`map`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.RwLockReadGuard.html#method.map) as yes you can't return references but have to return a RAII guard of sorts. But that doesn't allow an upgrade to a `RwLockWriteGuard` either..

Comment: Why do you need to upgrade the lock? Do you need to update an entry, after first being created?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Doesn't the entry creation itself necessitate the write lock, to prohibit readers?

Comment: @Xophmeister Yes, but when you're doing that, you don't need to hold any other read locks alive.

Comment: So it's a case of "drop the read lock, set the write lock" :+1: (I think my confusion was that my initial mental model was something like a read lock being a sub-state of a read-write lock.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the second part of your question (upgrade a read-lock into a write-lock), I have nothing more than dropping the read-lock before acquiring the write-lock. :-(

However, about the first part (return references to a hash-map content while this hash-map is mutated), I have a clue.

In such a situation, the referenced elements are fundamentally shared, and the ownership is not only the matter of the cache itself.
For example, if we decide to clear the cache at a certain point in the process, the elements which are still referenced must not be dropped.
Hence, we need a shared ownership for each value in the cache.
Instead of storing a `Value` we need to store an `Arc<Value>` in order to make the value outlive the cache if needed.

Please find below an attempt to implement this for an overly simplified situation (no generic type, hardcoded example): associate a string with a vector of codes for its chars.
The serial implementation relies on `RefCell` and `Rc`, while the parallel implementation relies on their synchronised equivalents `RwLock` and `Arc`.
In each demo, we can see that the address of the obtained slice stays the same when the same string is used for multiple fetches (the vector is cached).

```rust
mod serial {
    use std::{cell::RefCell, collections::HashMap, rc::Rc};

    pub struct Cache {
        data: RefCell<HashMap<String, Rc<Vec<u32>>>>,
    }

    impl Cache {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                data: RefCell::new(HashMap::new()),
            }
        }

        pub fn fetch(
            &self,
            key: &str,
        ) -> Rc<Vec<u32>> {
            if let Some(v) = self.data.borrow().get(key) {
                return Rc::clone(v);
            }
            let k = key.to_owned();
            let v = Rc::new(key.chars().map(|c| c as u32).collect());
            self.data.borrow_mut().insert(k, Rc::clone(&v));
            v
        }
    }

    pub fn demo() {
        println!("~~~~ serial demo ~~~~");
        let cache = Cache::new();
        for key in ["abc", "def", "ghi"] {
            for it in 0..2 {
                let v = cache.fetch(key);
                println!("iter {}: {:?} @ {:?}", it, v, v.as_ptr());
            }
        }
    }
}

mod parallel {
    use std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Arc, sync::RwLock};

    pub struct Cache {
        data: RwLock<HashMap<String, Arc<Vec<u32>>>>,
    }

    impl Cache {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                data: RwLock::new(HashMap::new()),
            }
        }

        pub fn fetch(
            &self,
            key: &str,
        ) -> Arc<Vec<u32>> {
            if let Some(v) = self.data.read().unwrap().get(key) {
                return Arc::clone(v);
            }
            let k = key.to_owned();
            let v = Arc::new(key.chars().map(|c| c as u32).collect());
            self.data.write().unwrap().insert(k, Arc::clone(&v));
            v
        }
    }

    pub fn demo() {
        println!("~~~~ parallel demo ~~~~");
        let cache = Cache::new();
        std::thread::scope(|s| {
            for it in 0..2 {
                s.spawn({
                    let cache = &cache;
                    move || {
                        for key in ["abc", "def", "ghi"] {
                            std::thread::yield_now();
                            let v = cache.fetch(key);
                            println!(
                                "thread {}: {:?} @ {:?}",
                                it,
                                v,
                                v.as_ptr()
                            );
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

fn main() {
    serial::demo();
    parallel::demo();
}
/*
~~~~ serial demo ~~~~
iter 0: [97, 98, 99] @ 0x557c23797bc0
iter 1: [97, 98, 99] @ 0x557c23797bc0
iter 0: [100, 101, 102] @ 0x557c23797c00
iter 1: [100, 101, 102] @ 0x557c23797c00
iter 0: [103, 104, 105] @ 0x557c23797c40
iter 1: [103, 104, 105] @ 0x557c23797c40
~~~~ parallel demo ~~~~
thread 1: [97, 98, 99] @ 0x7ff378000cc0
thread 0: [97, 98, 99] @ 0x7ff378000cc0
thread 1: [100, 101, 102] @ 0x7ff378000d00
thread 0: [100, 101, 102] @ 0x7ff378000d00
thread 1: [103, 104, 105] @ 0x7ff378000d40
thread 0: [103, 104, 105] @ 0x7ff378000d40
*/
```

Comment: Clever. Thank you :) One question to aid my understanding: in your `parallel::demo`, you simply take a reference to `cache` to move into the thread, rather wrapping the whole structure in an `Arc`. Is this simply by virtue of `cache`'s immutability -- i.e., we can have as many immutable borrows as we like -- then we rely on `RwLock`'s inner mutability to enable us to write to the hash map?

Comment: @Xophmeister Because the cache is fundamentally shared, we rely on [*interior mutability*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/) (thanks to `RefCell`/`RwLock`) then the `.fetch()` function only needs a shared reference (`&self`, no `mut`); this eases the shared usage of this structure. I used `move` for the closure in `spawn()` in order to copy the `it` counter (not reference it); but this implied moving the cache also. Then I used a common trick for this case: explicitly introduce a reference that will be moved (the reference itself not the value) into the closure.